# What kind of action is using Artificer items?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, unearthed-arcana, artificer

I was looking over the spell lists in the artificer class and realized that there are spells like haste that allow you to take a "use an object" action twice.

Does using the artificer's alchemical items count as using an object, or are they some other action? If they are something else, what type of action is using the artificer's items?

Comment: Hi there! We require each question post to focus on a single question, so that answers can focus on one question at a time. I have removed the second question, but you are welcome to post it in a second question post. (You can retrieve the text from the edit history, accessed by clicking "edited [time] ago" below the post.)

Comment: Are you referring to the version of the Artificer from [this Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/1_UA_Artificer_20170109.pdf)?

Answer (score 5):

Each of them is its own action.

> When you take your action on your turn, you can take
>   one of the actions presented here, an action you gained
>   from your class or a special feature, or an action that
>   you improvise.

They fall under the second category here - they're not any of the general actions covered in the Combat chapter, they are actions gained from a class feature.

> As an 
>   action, you
>   can 
>   reach 
>   into
>   your Alchemist
>   ’s Satchel [...]

They specify what kind of action they require - most of them use actions, but the Swift Step Draught is a bonus action.

Answer (score -5):

### No

Activating magical items does not fall under the "Use an Item" action - it is its own Action type (from the magical items section in the DMG).

An alchemist's satchel is a magic item, so "As an action, you can reach into your Alchemist’s Satchel,..." is activating a magic item.

This means that the extra action from the haste spell cannot be used to use an alchemist's satchel.

As an aside, it also means that the Thief Fast Hands ability also cannot be used on a satchel.